# R Iterate through data.frame rows using respective column value to return concatenated column names of any matching column values

Tags: r

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the steps needed to execute this in R. Essentially, I'm trying to take a row value, and compare its string against all of the other columns in my data frame, returning a concatenated list of column names where matches exist. Taking just the QB_slate_team column value to match against, I'd like to create the QB_Match column on the far right. Desired output showing team_stack_count table:

```
 QB_slate_team  RB_slate_team  WR_slate_team  QB_Match
 SEA            IND            GB             NA-NA
 GB             LV             GB             NA-WR_slate_team
```

[Detailed - Snag of team_stack_count table highlighting matched strings, as well as desired output column format]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxjs0.png

For example if QB_slate_team column row value = "GB" and WR_slate_team column row value = "GB" I'd expect the newly created QB_Match concatenated column to contain WR_slate_team among other NAs for columns that don't match.

After trying a bunch of different statements, this has gotten me the closest:

```
  team_stack_count$QB_Match <- apply(team_stack_count, 1, function(x) paste(names(x[x==team_stack_count$QB_slate_team]), collapse="-"))
```

But for some reason the team_stack_count$QB_slate_team that it is matching against seems to be a random static team name instead of iterating through the rows to get the appropriate value for each row-wise application.

Curious, is there any way to make the QB_slate_team row dynamic for the matching basis? (I believe I might be misunderstanding the apply statement and how it works - I'm open to any function that might help)

Answer (score 0):

The following does the trick by pivoting your data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-QB_slate_team) %>%
  mutate(match = if_else(QB_slate_team == value, name, 'NA')) %>%
  group_by(QB_slate_team) %>%
  mutate(QB_Match = str_c(match, collapse = '-')) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-match) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name) %>%
  select(- QB_Match, QB_Match)

#   QB_slate_team RB_slate_team WR_slate_team QB_Match        
#   <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         <chr>           
# 1 SEA           IND           GB            NA-NA           
# 2 GB            LV            GB            NA-WR_slate_team
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(QB_slate_team = c("SEA", "GB"), RB_slate_team = c("IND", 
"LV"), WR_slate_team = c("GB", "GB")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` as :

```
team_stack_count$QB_Match <- apply(team_stack_count, 1, function(x) {
                                    cols <- names(x)[-1]
                                    cols[x[-1] != x[1]] <- NA
                                    paste0(cols, collapse = '-')
                              })

team_stack_count
#  QB_slate_team RB_slate_team WR_slate_team         QB_Match
#1           SEA           IND            GB            NA-NA
#2            GB            LV            GB NA-WR_slate_team
```

**data**

```
team_stack_count <- structure(list(QB_slate_team = c("SEA", "GB"), 
RB_slate_team = c("IND", "LV"), 
WR_slate_team = c("GB", "GB")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a package called [libr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=libr) with a `datastep()` function that can do this and make it a little more readable.

The function will loop through each row, and allow you to write conditionals across the row.  You've got a tricky situation because you are also looping through the columns.  But the `datastep()` function has some features to deal with that.  In the code below, you will see the `data` object that represents your input data, and the `n.` variable that represents the current row number.  That is one way to access column values dynamically from within the datastep.

Also the `%eq%` operator included in this package will not fail if it encounters an NA value.  So it is safer than a double-equal (==).

```
library(libr)


df <- data.frame(QB_slate_team = c("SEA", "GB"),
                 RB_slate_team = c("IND", "LV"),
                 WR_slate_team = c("GB", "GB"))


df2 <- datastep(df, 
                drop = c("nm", "val"), {
  
  # Initialize QB_Match
  QB_Match <- ""
  
  # Loop through all columns except first
  for (nm in names(data)[-1]) {
    
    # Get appropriate value
    val <- ifelse(QB_slate_team %eq% data[[n., nm]], nm, "NA")

    # Initialize or append val to QB_Match
    QB_Match <- ifelse(QB_Match %eq% "", val, paste0(QB_Match, "-", val))

  }
})
```

Here is the result:

```
# QB_  slate_team RB_slate_team WR_slate_team         QB_Match
# 1           SEA           IND            GB            NA-NA
# 2            GB            LV            GB NA-WR_slate_team
```